# How to add constant height in exam class

Tags: formatting, pdftex, exam, height, questionnaire

I've MCQ Paper created using \documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam} ; here on very page I've to provide "Space for Rough Work". Height of "Space for Rough Work" is around 20% of page height. This height is constant on all pages . Kindly suggest, if there is any way to add constant height at the bottom of page reserved for Space for Rough work ? [image]

I tried `\setlength{\footskip}{200pt}` ; but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `\setlength\textheight{15cm}`, or some length that works for you. You can then push the footer *down* with, for example, `\setlength{\footskip}{8.5cm}`

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\setlength\textheight{15cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{8.5cm}

\providecommand{\myquestion}{%
\question 
Question text

\begin{choices}
\choice First choice
\choice Second choice
\choice Third choice
\choice Fourth choice
\end{choices}
\medskip
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit:

Since the space below `\textheight` is basically the footer, you could use the footer text as your effective header for this space. To do this, remove the `\setlength{\footskip}{8.5cm}` in the previous example, and customize your footer appearance as described in section 2.6 of the `exam` documentation. Note headers and footers for the first page are treated separately.

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\setlength\textheight{15cm}
\firstpagefooter{Space for Rough Work}{}{}
\firstpagefootrule
\runningfooter{Space for Rough Work}{}{}
\runningfootrule

\providecommand{\myquestion}{%
\question 
Question text

\begin{choices}
\choice First choice
\choice Second choice
\choice Third choice
\choice Fourth choice
\end{choices}
\medskip
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works; is there a way to add horizontal line after text height and "Space for Rough Work" as heading?

Comment: @PawanMude Yes. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: This is GR8; Working Perfectly. Thanks a lot !!!