# How to write below textheight and above footer

Tags: formatting, pdftex, exam, text-manipulation, height

MCQ Paper is mentioned below (Thanks to Erik) ;

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\setlength\textheight{15cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{8.5cm}

\providecommand{\myquestion}{%
\question 
Question text

\begin{choices}
\choice First choice
\choice Second choice
\choice Third choice
\choice Fourth choice
\end{choices}
\medskip
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion
\myquestion

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I want to add heading "Space for rough work" and Horizontal Line as mentioned in the diagram below (Highlighted in RED color).

[image]

Kindly advise?

Comment: Already answer is present at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309127/how-to-add-constant-height-in-exam-class